# Failed to minify the code from this file (styled.js)

Tags: webpack, material-ui, minify

We upgraded to MUI v5 and when we try to build the project we get the following error:
Failed to minify the code from this file:  ./node_modules/@mui/material/styles/styled.js:3:7

The project runs locally when using "npm start" but it failed when running the build script.